# undefined control sequence for \measuredangle

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I just installed MacTeX and texmaker.  I'm trying to create a measured angle.  The following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
The measure of $\angle{ABC}$ is expressed as $\measuredangle{ABC}$.
\end{document}
```

keeps getting me

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \measuredangle
l.4 ...angle{ABC}$ is expressed as $\measuredangle
{ABC}$.
```

I've tried web searches on my favorite engines for `latex undefined control sequence measuredangle`, but I keep results that are not useful; they're either listings of control sequences or people who had problems with different control sequences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) and search for the macro of interest. You'll see it in Table 202: Miscellaneous AMS Math Symbols. As such, it requires an AMS-related package. In this case, [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
The measure of $\angle{ABC}$ is expressed as $\measuredangle{ABC}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for not just the answer but for preemptively answering many potential future questions as well with that link!  In three minutes, when StackExchange thinks your answer is old and mature enough to accept, I'll accept it!